# kubernetes Seed provider couldn't lookup host cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, cassandra-3.0

Cassandra cluster on aws is failing to start.
The error is as follows.

> INFO  [main] 2018-10-11 08:11:42,794 DatabaseDescriptor.java:729 -
>   Back-pressure is disabled with strategy
>   org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9,
>   factor=5, flow=FAST}.
>
> WARN  [main] 2018-10-11 08:11:42,848 SimpleSeedProvider.java:60 - Seed
>   provider couldn't lookup host
>   cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local Exception
>   (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered
>   during startup: The seed provider lists no seeds. The seed provider
>   lists no seeds. ERROR [main] 2018-10-11 08:11:42,851
>   CassandraDaemon.java:708 - Exception encountered during startup: The
>   seed provider lists no seeds.

Here are my details of it.

```
$kubectl get pods                                                                                                                                                                                   [13:48]
NAME          READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
cassandra-0   1/1       Running            0          19h
cassandra-1   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   231        19h

$kubectl get services                                                                                                                                                                               [13:49]
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
cassandra    NodePort    100.69.201.208   <none>        9042:30000/TCP   1d
kubernetes   ClusterIP   100.64.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          15d

$kubectl get pvc                                                                                                                                                                                    [13:50]
NAME                            STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
cassandra-data-cassandra-0      Pending                                                                        fast           15d
cassandra-storage-cassandra-0   Bound     pvc-f3ff4203-c0a4-11e8-84a8-02c7556b5a4a   320Gi      RWO            gp2            15d
cassandra-storage-cassandra-1   Bound     pvc-1bc3f896-c0a5-11e8-84a8-02c7556b5a4a   320Gi      RWO            gp2            15d

$kubectl get namespaces                                                                                                                                                                             [13:53]
NAME          STATUS    AGE
default       Active    15d
kube-public   Active    15d
kube-system   Active    15d
```

Even the working pod is not loading storage.

It was working fine till I tried to change `MAX_HEAP_SIZE` from 1024M to 2048M.

After that even I deleted all old pods, services and created fresh, still it's not working.

Comment: What image are you using? How do you configure seeds?

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson image library/cassandra and seeds by env variable  - name: CASSANDRA_SEEDS
              value: "cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local"

Comment: Did you try following this guide? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/cassandra/

Comment: And you are using the default namespace?

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson yes using the default namespace and followed kubernetes example link you mentioned, except volume claim guides, my setup is hosted on AWS, somehow its volume claim was not working. Now I am using https://github.com/kubernetes/examples and building image, currently stuck with /etc/cassandra/cassandra-seed.so: invalid ELF header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the NodePort type. This will not make the service a headless service which is why the IP-address of the pod doesn't get resolved.

What you need to do is to create a seperate headless service. You also need to create your own Docker image and run a script in your entrypoint that will fetch all the ips for the service domain name.

You can look at the following project as an example: https://github.com/vyshane/cassandra-kubernetes/

Answer (score 0):

I did try Simon's code solution. But he gives me a tip that it has to be a headless service. however in my case I create headless service by adding "clusterIP: None". It give "Seed provider couldn't lookup host" without this line. 
I can not find DNS of pod(elassandra-0.elassandra.chargington.svc.cluster.local) , but i can find DNS of a service(elassandra.chargington.svc.cluster.local).

> Sometimes you don’t need or want load-balancing and a single service IP. In this case, you can create “headless” services by specifying "None" for the cluster IP (.spec.clusterIP).

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Here is my code

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: elassandra
  name: elassandra
  namespace: chargington
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - name: cassandra
      port: 9042
    - name: http
      port: 9200
    - name: transport
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9300
  selector:
    app: elassandra`

And in my statefulset I need to set
 `serviceName: elassandra` .  This is necessary to point the StatefulSet to the Service that will manage the domain for the pod's DNS names.

`---
apiVersion: "apps/v1beta1"
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: elassandra
  namespace: chargington
spec:
  serviceName: elassandra
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elassandra
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: elassandra
          image: strapdata/elassandra:6.2.3.3
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 7000
              name: intra-node
            - containerPort: 7001
              name: tls-intra-node
            - containerPort: 7199
              name: jmx
            - containerPort: 9042
              name: cql
            - containerPort: 9200
              name: http
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 9300
              name: transport
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: CASSANDRA_SEEDS
              value: elassandra-0.elassandra.chargington.svc.cluster.local
            - name: MAX_HEAP_SIZE
              value: 256M
            - name: HEAP_NEWSIZE
              value: 100M
            - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
              value: "Cassandra"
            - name: CASSANDRA_DC
              value: "DC1"
            - name: CASSANDRA_RACK
              value: "Rack1"
            - name: CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH
              value: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
          volumeMounts:
            - name: elassandra-data
              mountPath: /opt/elassandra-5.5.0.8/data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elassandra-data
        annotations: 
          volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: ""

      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi`

Answer (score 0):

If any one else still facing issue with Seed provider couldn't lookup host cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local Exception

For me the issue was the domain. I have configured the seed to be as:

```
cassandra-0.cassandra.<my-kube-namespace>.svc.<kube-domain>
```

In our company the k8s cluster was deployed with a cluster domain - and not default settings, so I had to use that domain and it started working for me.

To know the domain you may need to contact your local kube admin.